# How to access files inside a Python egg file?

Tags: python, egg

This might be a weird requirement but it's what I've run into. I Googled but yield nothing.

I'm coding an application who's using a lot of constant attributes / values recorded in an XML file (they'll not change so a static file), things work fine until I generated an egg file for it.

When the logic reaches the XML accessing part, I got one complaint like this:
/home/Workspace/my_proj/dist/mps-1.2.0_M2-py2.6.egg/mps/par/client/syntax/syntax.xml

Actually I've bundled the XML file in the path above but seems Python doesn't know how to access it.

The code to access the XML is as...

```
file_handler = open(path_to_the_file)
lines = file_handler.read().splitlines()
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you've still got this problem, check my answer here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735852/accessing-files-in-python-egg-from-inside-the-egg/13126365

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`egg` files are zipfiles, so you must access "stuff" inside them with the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module of the Python standard libraries, *not* with the built-in `open` function!

Comment: I read the doc for zipfile module and surely it could do the job. Thank you ~

Comment: you can even install them using, sudo easy_install your_eggfile

Answer (score 12):

If you want to access the contents inside the .egg file you can simply rename it and change extension from .egg to .zip and than unzip it.
Which will create a folder and the contents will be same as they were when it was a .egg file

for example  **brewer2mpl-1.4.1-py3.6.egg**
After Renaming **brewer2mpl-1.4.1-py3.6.zip**

Now if we open it, it'll get easily unzipped and the content will be put in a folder with same name in the same directory.
(tested on macOS Sierra)

Answer (score 2):

The `less` command on *nix systems can peek inside zip files. Therefore `less some.egg` will list the contents of a `.egg` file too.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `unzip file.egg`

---

You can install `unzip` on Debian/Ubuntu with

```sh
sudo apt install unzip
```

or on macOS by [installing Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then

```sh
brew install unzip
```

Answer (score 0):

## Access file from inside egg file

Yes, It is possible to read the files from inside egg file.

Egg file: `mps-1.2.0_M2-py2.6.egg` structure for module level example:

[image: mps-1.2.0_M2-py2.6.egg image]

In `driverfile.py`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import mps.par.client as syntaxpath
import os
path = os.path.dirname(syntaxpath.__file__)
element = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(path+'\\syntax\\syntax.xml').getroot()
print(element)
```

### Read xml file from inside an eggfile:

`PYTHONPATH=mps-1.2.0_M2-py2.6.egg python driverfile.py`

Answer (score 0):

i think by default eggs packing file under python won't add your xml inside to the pack