# pyspark: IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory (egg file import)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, egg

I am trying to run a pyspark job with an .egg file. The file has some code which references to .json files within the .egg file.

I get the absolute path of my .py file (in the .egg file) using os.path.dirname(**file**) and then append the path to it.

The path looks like:

`/private/var/folders/8b/85wbwwxn2n31zfl1dgcpcfxs1d0qjg/T/spark-347c3633-7d95-467c-a222-83965afc7f34/userFiles-d0c02f9a-3c54-4f50-bb14-550a1bdcc26b/normalize-3.0-py3.5.egg/i18naddress/data/us.json`

My directory structure is:

```
normalize-3.0-py3.5.egg
--i18naddress
----_init_.py (the class I call)
----data
------us.json
```

The relative path looks correct but however spark is unable to read these files and throws an IO error. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you were asking how to read files in an egg file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655352/how-to-access-files-inside-a-python-egg-file

Comment: Thanks zsxwing, this works!!!

Comment: Thanks that helped me too!